# check if current field value is EUR, USD... with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to check with a regexp the received field value is a string with 3 characters for currency like this:

```
EUR
USD
JPY
RUB
.
.
```

I have this function to check if it's only a number.

```
const onlyInteger = (oldValue, value) => {
  oldValue = '';
  if (value && String(value).trim().match(/^[+-]?\d+$/i)) {
    return value;
  }
  return oldValue;
}
```

Something like this function to check that user is writing three characters maximum.

Comment: what are `oldValue` and `value`?

Comment: oldValue is just an example, but oldValue does not exist! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? `oldValue` and `value` are both arguments to the function, what are they supposed to be?

Comment: They are the current values of the field. The user is writing and these are the values of the current field

Comment: Edited, forget the function. Thank you!

Comment: Please stop removing the JavaScript function. Your question is *unclear*. Please provide some additional explanation along with an example so we can better understand what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify a string is a currency:

```
str.match(/^(EUR|USD|JPY|RUB)$/)
```

To verify there are (any) 3 uppercase letters:

```
str.match(/^[A-Z]{3}$/)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't need the list. I only need to know that they are three characters and they are capitalized. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string only contains capitalized letters with the following regex test:

```
/^[A-Z]+$/.test(value)
```

Where `value` is the string to be tested.

You can also check that the string contains three characters by accessing its `length` property and making sure it's equal to `3`:

```
value.length == 3
```

---

In the code below `isCurrency` will return `true` if `value` is a three letter word. Else it will return `false`.

```js
const isCurrency = (value) => (/^[A-Z]+$/.test(value) && value.length == 3)

console.log(isCurrency('EUR'))
console.log(isCurrency('E1UR'))
console.log(isCurrency('EuR'))
```